# Pregunta sobre estructura web

Tags: html, css

queria estructurar bien esta pagina en html, seria todo secciones diriais? Lo de la izquierda seria aside o simplemente un nav? Quiero ver bien la estructura y soy nuevo en esto, gracias..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

El término **aside**  representa una sección de una página que consiste en contenido que está tangencialmente relacionado con el contenido que le rodea, que podría ser considerado independiente de ese contenido. Estas secciones son a menudo representadas como barras laterales o como inserciones y contienen una explicación al margen como una definición de glosario, elementos relacionados indirectamente, como publicidad, la biografía del autor, o en aplicaciones web, la información de perfil o enlaces a blogs relacionados.

el **nav** iría dentro del **aside** en el caso que has expuesto

**section** representa una sección genérica de un documento. Sirve para determinar qué contenido corresponde a qué parte de un esquema. Piensa en el esquema como en el índice de contenido de un libro; un tema común y subsecciones relacionadas.  Es, por lo tanto, una etiquéta semántica. Su funcionalidad principal es estructurar semánticamente un documento a la hora de ser representado por parte de un agente usuario. Por ejemplo, un agente de usuario que represente el documento en voz, podría exponer al usuario el índice de contenido por niveles para navegar rápidamente por las distintas partes.

Como ejemplo podrían haber varios section, uno con información de la empresa, otro section con los servicios que ofrece una empresa etc..

Luego cada **section** pueden tener los **article** que se necesiten, y estos representan una composición auto-contenida en un documento, página, una aplicación o en el sitio, que se destina a distribuir de forma independiente o reutilizable, por ejemplo, en la sindicación. Podría ser un mensaje en un foro, un artículo de una revista o un periódico, una entrada de blog, un comentario de un usuario, un widget interactivo o gadget, o cualquier otro elemento independiente del contenido.

Answer (score 0):

Que un menú (`nav`) se muestre en un lateral no quiere decir que tenga que ir en un `aside`. **Hay que analizar el contenido y para qué se va a usar, y no cómo se va visualizar o representar con CSS.**

El elemento `aside` se define así en el [estándar de HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) (traducción propia):

> El elemento `<aside>` representa una sección de la página que consiste en contenido que está tangencialmente relacionado con el contenido de la sección que lo contiene, y que puede ser considerado separadamente de este contenido. Este tipo de secciones se representa como barras laterales en tipografía impresa.
>
> El elemento puede ser usado para efectos tipográficos como citas sacadas del texto o barras laterales, para anuncios, para grupos de elementos `<nav>`, o para otro contenido que se considere separado del contenido principal al ancestro más cercano de sección.

Entonces, no hay necesidad semántica de tener el menú general de un sitio dentro de un `aside`, podría (y debería) ir solo con un `nav` sin necesidad de estar contenido en un `aside`. Por dos motivos:

1. Desde el punto de vista semántico: no es contenido tangencial al contenido principal de esa página en particular (o de cualquier otra, es tangencial a todo el sitio en general). Aunque este punto podría ser debatible.
2. Desde el punto de vista estructural: el `nav` no iría dentro de la sección que contiene el contenido principal de la página.

Sería una historia diferente si el `nav` en lugar de ser el menú principal de la página fuera, por ejemplo, en un blog y fueran enlaces a otros blogs relacionados. Entonces sí debería ir en un `aside` porque sería contenido relacionado con el contenido principal de la página.

Comment: Vale genial pero  va dentro del main no?

Comment: ¿El `nav`? No, ya que el menú general se repite en todas las páginas del sitio y no pertenece al contenido principal de ninguna de ellas en particular, entonces no se debe incluir en el `main` (como se indica en la [definición de `main` en el estándar HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/grouping-content.html#the-main-element))